# Flutter Web AutoSizeText disappearing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am trying to convert my app into Web. I have a text in an AutoSizeText widget as shown here:

```
  AutoSizeText(
               description,
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
               maxLines: 3,
    )
```

It all works well on a regular phone app, and the text shrinks into the lines.

When running it on web using `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html` the problem occurs. When shrinking the screen, the words just disappear and the text keeps its size.

If I run `flutter build web --web-renderer canvasKit --release` it works fine, the text shrinks but I have other problems in the app, some images don't show up so I cannot use it.

How can I do it so that the text shrinks into the lines when I use `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`?

Comment: Take a look at images with canvaskit: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/web-images#cross-origin-images.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this on the auto_size_text package's repo: https://github.com/simc/auto_size_text/issues/67

> As a workaround --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_EXPERIMENTAL_CANVAS_TEXT=false fixes the problem but it only works in release builds.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer. I have tried running this line but unfortunately It didn't work. 


 flutter run -d chrome --release --web-renderer html --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_EXPERIMENTAL_CANVAS_TEXT=false